# Ionic $state.go() is not working after receiving a pish notification

Tags: ionic-framework

Well, my App has several notifications and when the user clicks on notification I am redirecting him to a blank page and them redirecting again to the wanted page. I am doing it because I want to make sure the page will be reloaded.

Example:

page1 - list of new items
page2 - blank page to redirect

The user is on page1, ok?

When I send a push notification I redirect him to page2 and then back to page1 to make sure the page1 will be refreshed.

The problem is.... state.go is not working on page2. It just stops and do nothing else. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason for state.go to not work. 
and moreover instead of going to page2. you can simply update your $state variable and make a 2 way binding to them. thus your page1 can refresh without going to Page2.